# NSLayoutConstraints crashing on ios7 but not on ios8

Tags: ios7, swift, ios8, xcode6, nslayoutconstraint

I've setup in a UIViewController some layout constraints which works fine on ios8. But as soon as I run it on ios7 i've got the following error :

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UIView layoutSublayersOfLayer:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-2935.137/UIView.m:8803
```

Here is my code :

```
class DatacenterIndicatorViewController: UIViewController {

let sideMargins:Float = 12.0   
var dataCenterPollingLabel:UILabel = UILabel()
var dataCenterAlarmLabel:UILabel = UILabel()

//MARK: - Life cycle
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.view.addSubview(dataCenterPollingLabel)
    self.view.addSubview(dataCenterAlarmLabel)
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    self.reloadData()
}

func reloadData() {
    self.setupAlarmLabel()
    self.setupPollingLabel()
    self.generateConstraints()
}

func setupPollingLabel() {
   // some graphic setup
}

func setupAlarmLabel() {
     // some graphic setup
}

func generateConstraints() {
    self.dataCenterPollingLabel.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
    self.dataCenterAlarmLabel.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)

    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: dataCenterPollingLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: dataCenterAlarmLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: dataCenterAlarmLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: dataCenterPollingLabel, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0))
    self.view.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat(NSString(format:"H:|-==%f-[dataCenterPollingLabel]-==%f-[dataCenterAlarmLabel]-==%f-|", sideMargins, sideMargins, sideMargins), options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.allZeros, metrics: nil, views: ["dataCenterPollingLabel": dataCenterPollingLabel, "dataCenterAlarmLabel": dataCenterAlarmLabel]))

}
}
```

What is wrong in my code ? I can even know where to look for some errors, everything looks fine to me.

Comment: Are there any unsatisfiable constraints being written in console ?

Comment: No, nothing more than the assertion failure message

Comment: check if some view has zero size when you add the constraints

Comment: How come it can happen in ios7 but not in ios8 ?

Comment: Did you found it what the problem was? I'm having the same issue here..

Comment: Still looking for an answer, if I find anything i'll update this post.You should check if in storyboard you let the margin option checked on your constraints.

Answer (score 12):

I faced the same issue in iOS 7 version. Calling  self.view.layoutIfNeeded() function instead of super.viewDidLayoutSubviews() function at the end of the viewDidLayoutSubviews method solved the issue.

Code snippet

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

    // Your statements
    self.reloadData()

    //Write the below statement at the end of the function
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

}
```

Comment: This fixed things for me. I was updating constraints in viewDidLayoutSubviews and getting a crash on iOS 7 but not iOS 8.